# How to select the GET data from a controller and use it as a POST value to another controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using a backend server that a foreign key variable. I want to pass the value on a POST call via select options. So I take the controller and get all the values that I need. Problem is that angular says that the values are null. 
How can I make it see the values?

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="cod_fac">Codul Facultatii</label>
     <div ng-controller="FacultateaCtrl">
       <select class="form-control" name="cod_fac" ng-model="cod_fac">
        <option  ng-controller="FacultateaCtrl" ng-repeat="facultate in facultati" value="{{ facultate.id }}">
          {{ facultate.denumirea }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Keep in mind that I am calling a controller in another controller.

Comment: use a service to communicate

Answer (score 0):

Declare a service like so :

```
angular
      .module('yourModule', [])
      .service('yourService', yourService);

 // if you need any deps in this service
 yourService.$inject = [];

 function yourService(){
   var this = service;
   service.sharedData = [];
 }
```

Then you can access it by injecting 'yourService' into your controller, and you'll be able to access everything that is on the service object.